# Convert mouseup function to another function and use it in a jQueryUI slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to rewrite some code that is incorrectly using mouseup event on jQueryUI sliders instead of correctly using the sliders stop event.

The code I have looks like:

```
jQuery('body').on('mouseup', '.price-slider-range,.length-slider-range', function(e){

//Do something fancy
});
```

and the sliders code look like this:

```
    jQuery( ".length-slider-range" ).slider({
            range: true,
            min: <?php echo ($Priceresults['min_length']>0 ? $Priceresults['min_length'] : '0' ); ?>,
            max: <?php echo ($Priceresults['max_length']>0 ? $Priceresults['max_length'] : '0' ); ?>,
            values: [ <?php if($lengthMIN>0){ echo $lengthMIN;}else {echo '0';} ?>, <?php if($lengthMAX>0){ echo $lengthMAX; }else{ echo ($Priceresults['max_length']>0 ? $Priceresults['max_length'] : '0' ); } ?> ],
            slide: function( event, ui ) {  jQuery( "#length-amount" ).val(  ui.values[ 0 ] + "cm - " + ui.values[ 1 ]+"cm" );
            }
 });
```

I am wondering how I can convert the original mouseup function to a "normal" function and then use it inside the .slider stop event so that it will end up to look like this:

```
jQuery( ".length-slider-range" ).slider({
            range: true,
            min: <?php echo ($Priceresults['min_length']>0 ? $Priceresults['min_length'] : '0' ); ?>,
            max: <?php echo ($Priceresults['max_length']>0 ? $Priceresults['max_length'] : '0' ); ?>,
            values: [ <?php if($lengthMIN>0){ echo $lengthMIN;}else {echo '0';} ?>, <?php if($lengthMAX>0){ echo $lengthMAX; }else{ echo ($Priceresults['max_length']>0 ? $Priceresults['max_length'] : '0' ); } ?> ],
            slide: function( event, ui ) {  jQuery( "#length-amount" ).val(  ui.values[ 0 ] + "cm - " + ui.values[ 1 ]+"cm" );
            },

                stop: function(event, ui) { 
               //Do the fancy stuff from the now removed mouseup function
             }
 });
```

Comment: could you please post `mouseup` fancy function so that we can guide you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I wasn't able to properly rewrite the mouseup code, I chose the easier workaround, changing the event to double-click:

```
jQuery('body').on('dblclick', '.price-slider-range,.length-slider-range', function(e){

//Do something fancy
});
```

and triggering the double-click event on stop, like so:

```
jQuery( ".length-slider-range" ).slider({
            //range: true,
            range: "min",
            step: 0.01,
            min: <?php echo ($Priceresults['min_length']>0 ? $Priceresults['min_length'] : '0' ); ?>,
            max: <?php echo ($Priceresults['max_length']>0 ? $Priceresults['max_length'] : '0' ); ?>,
            values: [ <?php if($lengthMIN>0){ echo $lengthMIN;}else {echo '0';} ?>, <?php if($lengthMAX>0){ echo $lengthMAX; }else{ echo ($Priceresults['max_length']>0 ? $Priceresults['max_length'] : '0' ); } ?> ],
            slide: function( event, ui ) {  jQuery( "#length-amount" ).val(  ui.values[ 0 ] + "cm - " + ui.values[ 1 ]+"cm" );
            },
            stop: function( event, ui ) {
                jQuery(".length-slider-range").trigger( "dblclick" );
            }
```

And it works fine.